# NUnit tests not running on simple examples

Tags: c#, nunit

I've tried two very simple tutorials on NUnit on a .NET solution.  One example is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9e3inTSruQ).  In both cases, when I get to the point of running the first tests, test explorer shows the test as not run.  I'm using VS 2019, .NET 4.7.2/Core 3.1.

There's probably just a simple step or configuration I'm missing.  Any clues as to what I'm missing are appreciated!

Code:

```
namespace UnitTesting
{
    public class SerialPortParser
    {
        public static int ParsePort(string port)
        {
            if (!port.StartsWith("COM"))
                throw new FormatException("Port is not in a correct format.");
            else
            {
                const int lastIndexOfPrefix = 3;
                string portNumber = port.Substring(lastIndexOfPrefix);
                return int.Parse(portNumber);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace UnitTesting.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SerialPortParserTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void ParsePort_COM1_Returns1()
        {
            int result = SerialPortParser.ParsePort("COM1");
            // Assert.That(<ActualResult>, <ExpectedResult>);
            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(1));

            //Assert.AreEqual(1,result);  -- older way of writing it
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

Project files.  UnitTesting.Tests.prj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.17.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\UnitTesting\UnitTesting.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

UnitTesting.prj (the code):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

And the solution file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.30104.148
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "UnitTesting", "UnitTesting.csproj", "{20C01BDF-2F9D-4B03-8A51-023664EFF9EB}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "UnitTesting.Tests", "..\UnitTesting.Tests\UnitTesting.Tests.csproj", "{59BE97E7-3515-461D-A485-3E0197557137}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {20C01BDF-2F9D-4B03-8A51-023664EFF9EB}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {20C01BDF-2F9D-4B03-8A51-023664EFF9EB}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {20C01BDF-2F9D-4B03-8A51-023664EFF9EB}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {20C01BDF-2F9D-4B03-8A51-023664EFF9EB}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {59BE97E7-3515-461D-A485-3E0197557137}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {59BE97E7-3515-461D-A485-3E0197557137}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {59BE97E7-3515-461D-A485-3E0197557137}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {59BE97E7-3515-461D-A485-3E0197557137}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {B35CC293-9961-4BB3-80AF-A62B13D54817}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: Have you tried to run them from console, using `dotnet test`? Maybe you've just missed test adapter package

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski  Thanks.  When I run dotnet test, I see nothing.  It pauses for a number of seconds then just returns to the CLI prompt.

Comment: You have to reveal everything (especially the project files, where you can make tons of mistakes on adding the references).

Comment: @LexLi Thanks and done!

Comment: Sadly Microsoft made it very complicated to get things working. You missed a reference of `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`. Then both VS for Windows and for Mac is going to happily execute the test cases for you.

Comment: @LexLi  And so I did!  No idea how to find such an omission without help like SO.  Thank you!